# Send email with Google App Engine and store it in Sent Mail in Gmail

Tags: google-app-engine, gmail

I create a web application in Python for Google App Engine that sends a mail when I make some stuff. I used my Gmail account to send the email and I would like to save that email in my sent mail. It's possible?

Comment: Why don't you send the email to your gmail account as well. Then you can create a filter to skip the inbox and mark it as read.

Comment: becouse i wont to be sure that the email get to the other addresss

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No this is not possible since Google App Engine is not directly connected with your Gmail account and in the sent items only items that are sent through Gmail are appearing. As  [Sebastian Kreft](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12466740/send-mail-with-google-app-engine-and-save-on-gmail#comment16769101_12466740) pointed it out, you could sent a copy to yourself and create a filter for it.

I'm not sure if the non delivery reports are coming back on sender's email address, but either case make sure that you have access to that email or [set the reply_to field](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/emailmessagefields).

Comment: ok thanks, but there is a method to make sure that the email arrived?

Comment: @GeoMad89 I updated my answer, but I'm not sure if it actually going to work in case of wrong email or something..

Answer (score 0):

You cannot be sure your e-mail will reach it's destination with app engine mail api, because you never receive   any information about e-mail delivery from the GAE mail api and you cannot use a return-path.

Because of that I use app engine together with Amazon SES.

Another trick is to use the gmail api of google apps script:
See: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/service_gmail
Apps script is also able to talk to GAE.